# how to make an image map responsive?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a responsive image map. It works perfectly when its in desktop mode but when i'm changing to mobile mode the hyperlink does not work anymore .I checked few videos and read online since yesterday but still can not find out where is the problem .Any help will be appreciated in advance.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <title>Responsive Image Maps </title>
 <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True" />
 <meta name="MobileOptimized" content="320" />
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, target-densitydpi=160dpi, initial-scale=1" />
 <script src="../../js/ios-orientationchange-fix.min.js"></script>
 <style>
 body {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 }
 
 
 img {
  border: none;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: auto;
 }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
<img  src="test.jpg" usemap="#image-map">
<map name="#image-map">
<area  alt="" title="" href="#" shape="rect" coords="915,1856,1012,1953" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />
<area  alt="" title="" href="tel:513-442-7777" shape="rect" coords="1045,1859,1142,1956" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />
<area  alt="" title="" href="mailto:test@test.CA" shape="rect" coords="1176,1856,1273,1953" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />
</map>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.rwdImageMaps.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
 $('img[usemap]').rwdImageMaps();
 
 $('area').on('click', function() {
  alert($(this).attr('alt') + ' clicked');
 });
});
</script>




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You may have made the image responsive, but the coordinates for the map are static and that's why they don't work properly when the map size changes. You may want to consider ditching the image map in favor of Geolocation links.

Comment: Thank you @ScottMarcus for taking your time to answer my question.I'm new in web designing can you explain me a bit more .Like whats Geolocation links ?

Comment: Alternately, you could use invisible `<a>` elements over the picture, absolutely positioned by percentage.  That way as the page/image scales so too would the links.

Comment: @AlexanderNied if i use <a> tag it will target everything no?

Comment: _if i use <a> tag it will target everything no?_ -- Well, to do that plan, you would use specific ID's in order to appropriately target the element with CSS to size and position it over the target.  Is that what you are asking?

Comment: I tried it but did not worl :/

Comment: @Alexander Nied if you could show me an expamle i would really appreciate your help bcz im working on this for two days and i can not find out whats wrong

Comment: @marie - take a look at the answer I submitted-- it should hopefully provide you with a start for what you are attempting to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be accomplished with a simple, [old-school responsive image](https://alistapart.com/article/fluid-images) and floating anchors sized and positioned in percentages.  Try loading the below snippet at a few different screen widths.  You'll see the floating anchor with a red border hovering over Jupiter at all screen widths-- the picture grows and shrinks with the viewport, and the link adjusts its dimensions accordingly.

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 812px; /*actual width of image-- behaves strangely if exceeding this*/
  position: relative;
}

#wrapper img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

#anchor-jupiter {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 44%;
  width: 17%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 39.75%;
  top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/myS74.png" />
  <a id="anchor-jupiter" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jupiter" target="_blank"></a>
</div>
```

Remove the border, and you have something that behaves a lot like an image map, but is fully configurable with CSS and able to be made responsive:

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
    max-width: 812px; /*actual width of image-- behaves strangely if exceeding this*/
  position: relative;
}

#wrapper img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

#anchor-jupiter {
  height: 44%;
  width: 17%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 39.75%;
  top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/myS74.png" />
  <a id="anchor-jupiter" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jupiter" target="_blank"></a>
</div>
```

Now, you lose a few things from image maps with this approach-- since you are using anchors sized with CSS, you don't have [full SVG-like shape support that you have with image maps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map).  However, you have some limited shape support with CSS.

Also, note that there are [newer formats for responsive images available](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images) -- although you would have to check browser support and provide fallbacks.

Comment: Thank you so much its more clear now but just one more question . how do u get the  coordinates for jupiter ? like if i want to get the Coordinate for venus and urano how i can do that ?

Comment: @marie - Honestly, just educated guessing and trial and error.  I gave the link a border to start so I could see its bounds.  Then I estimated that, in the picture, Jupiter takes up the bottom half of the screen (`top: 50%`, `height: 50%`), is maybe one tenth the total width (`width: 10%`) and fell a bit short of the middle (`left: 40%`).  From there I adjusted those properties up and down until it fit over Jupiter.  Once it fit, I removed the border.  You can do all this in your code and keep refreshing the page, but doing it in the Chrome devtools in realtime will be faster.  Good luck!

Comment: Got it Thank you so much people like you make this world beautiful